# Calculating thermal force generated

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

Let's say you have a car that weights 1000kg traveling at 25m/s that slams into a brick wall and stops immediately.  Using (F) = 1/2 *(m)*(v)^2, where m is 1,000 kg and v is 25, the car generates 312,500J of thermal force (kinetic energy transforms to thermal energy via friction, right?).

My question is what happens if you have 2 cars, both traveling in the opposite direction slamming into each other head on and stopping immediately.  How would you calculate the total amount of thermal energy created (/transformed).  Would it be:

A) M = 1000kg, V = 50, F = 1,250,000J
Double the velocity as the 2 cars are traveling in the opposite direction but leave the mass the same.

B) M = 2000kg, V = 25, F = 625,000J
Double the mass as 2 cars are involved but leave the velocity the same.

C) M = 2000kg, V = 50, F = 2,500,000J
Double the mass as 2 cars are involved and double the velocity as they are both traveling 25 m/s in the opposite direction.

I believe the correct answer would be C but could you please double check.

Comment: Use the equations (total KE before) = (total KE after) and see what you get.

Comment: Force and energy are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The car alone does not produce thermal energy in the idealised case, because all the energy is used to keep the mass in motion. Now we assume that the two cars are in a closed system, so the cars can neither create nor destroy energy, i.e. they drive towards each other at a constant speed. With these assumptions, we set up this equation, where $ \Delta U $ is the internal energy in the form of, for example, thermal energy.

$$ \sum E_{kin} = \sum E_{kin}' + \Delta U $$

$$ \frac{m_1 v_1^2}{2} + \frac{m_2 v_2^2}{2} = \frac{(m_1 + m_2) v'^2}{2} + \Delta U $$

As both cars come to an immediate stop, the end speed $ v' $ equals zero and since $ m = m_1 = m_2 $ and $  v = v_1 = v_2 $, $ \Delta U $ can be calculated using

$$ \Delta U = m v^2 = 1000\,\text{kg} \times \left(25\,\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}\right)^2 = 625\,000\,\text{J}. $$